# Ruby class instance variables vs php properties

Tags: php, ruby

In php I might have a class like so:

```
class Item
    public $quality = 10

    public function reduceQuality()
    {
        $this->quality -= 1;
    }
}

$item = new Item;
$item->reduceQuality();
print $item->quality; // outputs 9
```

How would I achieve similar in ruby? I have something like:

```
class Item

    attr_reader :quality

    @quality = 10

    def reduce_quality()
        @quality -= 1
    end
end

item = Item.new
item.reduce_quality # `reduce_quality': undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
item.quality
```

I understand Ruby has instance variables and class variables. I am trying to define an instance variable on the object when it's created. What's best practice to do something like this, bearing in mind I might extend the class and I want the `quality` property to be inherited or overridable?

e.g.

```
class SuperItem < Item
    @quality = 50
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set value in the initializer.

```
class Item

  attr_reader :quality

  def initialize
    @quality = default_quality
  end

  def reduce_quality
    @quality -= 1
  end

  def default_quality
    1
  end
end

class SuperItem < Item
  def default_quality
    50
  end
end
```

Comment: can you explain why this is required? I'm just trying to understand the concepts. Also, if my initializer does other things (such as set other instance variables), will I need to call the parent initializer from inherited classes?

Comment: I see, so I set my initial instance properties via a method rather than a property directly on the class

Comment: Because what you do in the question is setting `@quality` on the class object (`Item` itself, not a possible future instance of it)

Comment: @harryg: You can set your instance variables however you like, but instance variables always belong to the instance, i.e. `self`, and in a class declaration body, `self` is the class. (Remember, classes are objects just like any other object, they are instances of class `Class`, and they can have instance variables just like any other object.)